# connection to socket in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i want to create simple chat application using MEAN stack, but i failed connecting to socket.io. here is my connection code

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
 io.on('connection', function(){ 
console.log('a user connected');
 });
//configure port
server.listen('8000');
console.log('server running at port 8000');
```

when i run node server i only get console message as "server running at port 8000"
but not "a user connected", is my socket working fine or i am not done with the socket. i would be glad on any responses.

Comment: Do you have client code connecting on socket.io?  What basic debugging steps have you take to see whether there is an incoming connection?

Comment: @jfriend00 Not yet, i just want to be sure that my socket is running fine with console message. and then start with client side, am i wrong in this enlighten me buddy i am very new to this.

Comment: `io.on('connection', ...)` will ONLY happen when a client actually connects.  You won't get that event until there's a client.  Your socket.io code will not report any message until you have a client that actually connects.  Nothing   else to do other than make a client that actually coonnects.

Comment: i am so much grateful for you @jfriend00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function call only on new socket connection:

`io.on('connection', function(){ 
    console.log('a user connected');
 });`

To create this connection you can create simple HTML page with script like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
</script>
```

For more details, please visit [this page.](http://socket.io/docs/)